# Input 3 Integers and arrange it in ascending order using if else statement only

Tags: java

How do i arrange this in ascending order?

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class Main{
    public static void main(String args[]){

        Scanner in= new Scanner(System.in);

        int num = in.nextInt();
        int num2 = in.nextInt();
        int num3 = in.nextInt();

        if (num > num2 && num > num3){
            System.out.printf("%d,%d,%d",num, num2, num3);
        } else if (num2 > num3){
            System.out.printf("%d,%d,%d",num2, num3,num);
        } else {
            System.out.printf("%d,%d,%d",num3, num2, num);
        }
    }
}
```

*Input: 6 1 3
Expected  output: 1 3 6*

*Input: 20 10 2
Expected output:  2 10 20*

Comment: If `num > num2` and `num > num3` what is the order between `num2` and `num3`? Why do you start printing the found largest number when it's supposed to be ascending?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to Sort Numbers with If Statements (Java)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32531962/how-to-sort-numbers-with-if-statements-java)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You missed some checks and your existing checks must be reversed.

```
if (num > num2 && num > num3) {
    if (num2 > num3) {
        System.out.printf("%d, %d, %d\n", num3, num2, num);
    } else {
        System.out.printf("%d, %d, %d\n", num2, num3, num);
    }
} else if (num2 > num3) {
    if (num > num3) {
        System.out.printf("%d, %d, %d\n", num3, num, num2);
    } else {
        System.out.printf("%d, %d, %d\n", num, num3, num2);
    }
} else {
    if (num > num2) {
        System.out.printf("%d, %d, %d\n", num2, num, num3);
    } else {
        System.out.printf("%d, %d, %d\n", num, num2, num3);
    }
}
```

But you really should use some default techniques to sort your objects, like a List, which is easier to read and to expand.

```
List<Integer> list = Arrays.asList(6, 1, 3);
Collections.sort(list);
System.out.println(list);
```

Answer (score -1):

```
if (num < num2 && num < num3 && num2<num3){
  System.out.printf("%d,%d,%d",num, num2,num3);
} else if (num2 < num3 && num2<num && num3<num){
  System.out.printf("%d,%d,%d",num2, num3,num);
} else if(num3<num && num3<num2) {
  System.out.printf("%d,%d,%d",num3, num2,num);
} else {    
System.out.printf("%d,%d,%d",num, num3,num2);
}
```

Comment: Does not work if num2 is biggest and num3 > num. Also if num3 is biggest and num > num2.